# d3.js - response layout on `height` change `svg` content still stable (not resize)

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I am trying to make a `d3.js` responsive layout. I find a demo for responsive approach. In this demo, only the width `resize` works. when you re-size the `height` the `svg` children not responsive.

what is wrong here?

code :

```
var chart = $("#chart"),
    aspect = chart.width() / chart.height(),
    container = chart.parent();
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    var targetWidth = container.width();
    chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
    chart.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
}).trigger("resize");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawnbot/BJLe6/)

Comment: I am not aware, can you give more info? or can you update my fiddle?

Comment: Your fiddle works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.  I cannot test Safari

Comment: Try this? http://jsfiddle.net/BJLe6/797/ I added none to your svg preserveAspectRatio tag (And now also corrected a typo)

Comment: @Grallen can you have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/BJLe6/799/

Comment: I'm sorry.  I can't reproduce the issue, so I don't think I can further troubleshoot, even though I wish I could. Withdrawing my answer.  Good luck.